# How do I create a 2D array?

Tags: python

I would like to create a 2D array look something like this using a loop in python:

```
[[1,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,1,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,1,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,1,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,1,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,1]]
```

1's index increase by 1 next row and rest of elements in array is filled 0.

Comment: I reopened the question because this is not a duplicate to the linked question, despite having a similar title. This question should be closed instead because it is too broad, without a specific question to an attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can run following code

```
arr = []
for i in range(6):
    arr.append([])
    for j in range(6):
        if i == j:
            arr[i].append(1)
        else:
            arr[i].append(0)

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 3):

P.S: There are several ways to construct such a matrix. This is one way of doing it using for loops as you asked. The matrix you need is called an **identity matrix**

```
size = 6
arr = [[0]*size for _ in range(size)] # Initialize 6 lists all with zeros

# Now change the value to 1 on the diagonal enteries
for i in range(size):
    arr[i][i] = 1

print (arr)   

# [[1 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 1 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 1 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 1 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

**Alternative 1 using NumPy**: Similar to the above case, initialize a 6x6 matrix of zeros *using NumPy* and then just replace 0 by 1 on the diagonal.

```
import numpy as np

size = 6
arr = np.zeros((size, size))

for i in range(size):
    arr[i][i] = 1

print (arr)
```

**Alternative 2**

```
import numpy as np
size = 6
arr = np.eye(size)
```

**Alternative 3**

```
np.identity(6)
```

Comment: The nested list in alternative 1 is unnecessary and inefficient. `for i in range(size): arr[i][i] = 1` would be enough.

Comment: @blhsing: So shall I delete it? I just tried to provide several options to give a better perspective

Comment: You can improve it instead.

Comment: @blhsing : How about now? Thanks for the suggestion :) Appreciated

Comment: My suggestion was meant for your alternative 1. Your answer now looks confusing because the main answer converts the Python list of lists to a numpy array unnecessarily, while your alternative 1 is still using the inefficient nested loop.

Comment: @blhsing : Oh sorry, I got confused. I see your point. Let me switch back :)